# error LNK2005: __NULL_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR already defined in mincore.lib

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, uwp

I added [/WHOLEARCHIVE linker option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/wholearchive-include-all-library-object-files?view=msvc-170) to my UWP app to make static objects from a static library to be linked to the app:

[image]

And got the following linker errors:

```
2>mincore.lib(api-ms-win-core-com-l1-1-1.dll) : error LNK2005: __NULL_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR already defined in mincore.lib(api-ms-win-core-com-l1-1-0.dll)
2>mincore.lib(api-ms-win-core-com-l1-1-2.dll) : error LNK2005: __NULL_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR already defined in mincore.lib(api-ms-win-core-com-l1-1-0.dll)
2>mincore.lib(api-ms-win-core-com-l1-1-3.dll) : error LNK2005: __NULL_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR already defined in mincore.lib(api-ms-win-core-com-l1-1-0.dll)
2>mincore.lib(api-ms-win-core-console-l2-1-0.dll) : error LNK2005: __NULL_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR already defined in mincore.lib(api-ms-win-core-com-l1-1-0.dll)
2>mincore.lib(api-ms-win-core-console-l2-2-0.dll) : error LNK2005: __NULL_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR already defined in mincore.lib(api-ms-win-core-com-l1-1-0.dll)
2>mincore.lib(api-ms-win-core-console-l3-2-0.dll) : error LNK2005: __NULL_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR already defined in mincore.lib(api-ms-win-core-com-l1-1-0.dll)
2>mincore.lib(api-ms-win-core-file-l2-1-0.dll) : error LNK2005: __NULL_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR already defined in mincore.lib(api-ms-win-core-com-l1-1-0.dll)
2>mincore.lib(api-ms-win-core-file-l2-1-1.dll) : error LNK2005: __NULL_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR already defined in mincore.lib(api-ms-win-core-com-l1-1-0.dll)
2>mincore.lib(api-ms-win-core-file-l2-1-2.dll) : error LNK2005: __NULL_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR already defined in mincore.lib(api-ms-win-core-com-l1-1-0.dll)
2>mincore.lib(api-ms-win-core-file-l2-1-3.dll) : error LNK2005: __NULL_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR already defined in mincore.lib(api-ms-win-core-com-l1-1-0.dll)
2>mincore.lib(api-ms-win-core-firmware-l1-1-0.dll) : error LNK2005: __NULL_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR already defined in mincore.lib(api-ms-win-core-com-l1-1-0.dll)
```

...

what are they?

My app properties:

[image]

Comment: Have you checked the document [Linker Tools Error LNK2005](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/tool-errors/linker-tools-error-lnk2005?view=msvc-170)? What is your UWP project specificall? UWP c++/winrt project?

Comment: @JunjieZhu-MSFT It is UWP c++ project.

Comment: I tried C++/CX and C++/WinRT UWP project, but I have a lot of stuff in my Command line "All Options" by default and it can't be built after I add /WHOLEARCHIVE. Did I miss any settings?